# Python array segmented in ranges

Tags: python, arrays, range

I have the following array `[1, 4, 7, 9, 2, 10, 5, 8]` and I need to separate the array in 3 different arrays: one for values between 0 and 3, anther for 3 to 6 and anther for 6 and 25.The result must be something like that:

```
array1 = [1, 2]
array2 = [4, 5]
array3 = [7, 9, 10, 8]
```

Any idea about how to do it simple?

Comment: it does sound simple. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, define your "pole" numbers
- Second, generate your intervals from those "pole" numbers
- Third, define as many lists as there are intervals.
- Then for each interval, scan the list and appends items in the relevant list if they belong to the interval

code:

```
source = [1, 4, 7, 9, 2, 10, 5, 8]

poles = (0,3,6,25)
intervals = [(poles[i],poles[i+1]) for i in range(len(poles)-1)]

# will generate: intervals = [(0,3),(3,6),(6,25)]

output = [list() for _ in range(len(intervals))]

for out,(start,stop) in zip(output,intervals):
    for s in source:
        if start <= s <stop:
            out.append(s)

print(output)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 9, 10, 8]]
```

This solution has the advantage of being adaptable to more than 3 lists/intervals by adding more "pole" numbers.

EDIT: There's a nice & fast solution (`O(log(N)*N)`) if the output lists order don't matter:

- first sort the input list
- then generate the sliced sub-lists using `bisect` which returns insertion position of the provided numbers (left & right)

like this:

```
import bisect

source = sorted([1, 4, 7, 9, 2, 10, 5, 8])

poles = (0,3,6,25)

output = [source[bisect.bisect_left(source,poles[i]):bisect.bisect_right(source,poles[i+1])] for i in range(len(poles)-1)]

print(output)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: not necessarily, most important is to count the number of elements per range, again thanks for your help!

Comment: the yes, `bisect` is the way. Elegant and fast!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a very simple way using a combination of a for loop and range functions:

```
lists = ([], [], [])

for element in [1, 4, 7, 9, 2, 10, 5, 8]:
    if element in range(0, 3):
        lists[0].append(element)

    elif element in range(3, 6):
        lists[1].append(element)


    elif element in range(6, 25):
        lists[2].append(element)



array1, array2, array3 = lists
```

Answer (score 0):

*"One-line"* solution using `set.intersection(*others)` and `range(start, stop[, step])` functions:

```
l = [1, 4, 7, 9, 2, 10, 5, 8]
l1, l2, l3 = (list(set(l).intersection(range(3))), list(set(l).intersection(range(3,6))), list(set(l).intersection(range(6,25))))

print(l1)
print(l2)
print(l3)
```

The output:

```
[1, 2]
[4, 5]
[8, 9, 10, 7]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#set.intersection